# Jquery UI Snap smooth to browser edges

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, transition, draggable, droppable

I am using Jquery UI to snap a container into my browser edges,
based on the position.

I want that my container get a smooth transition when it gets dropped.
I tried many different option with .animate etc. but no options seems to work without any problems.

My code:

```js
$('.container').draggable({
  grid: false,
  snap: 'body',
  snapMode: 'inner',
  snapTolerance: 40,
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css({
      left: 'auto',
      right: 'auto',
      top: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto'
    });
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {

    var cWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
    var cHeight = $(window).height() / 2;

    if (ui.position.left > cWidth) {
      $(this).css({
        left: 'auto',
        right: 15
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        right: 'auto',
        left: 15
      });
    }

    if (ui.position.top > cHeight) {
      $(this).css({
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: 15
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        bottom: 'auto',
        top: 15
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8u3x7ma/12/

I am very thankful for every help.